# How to put other image extensions in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: image, laravel, validation, upload, laravel-5

I have this solution to upload the image of the user profile by picking up the Storage folder that is working.
The question is how can I play the extension of the image to the bank or how can I validate in the controller the other extensions can anyone help me?

**Controller**

```
public function getAccount()
{
    return view('account', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
}

public function postSaveAccount(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:100'
    ]);

    $user           = Auth::user();
    $old_email      = $user->email;
    $user->email    = $request['email'];


    $user->update();
    $file = $request->file('image');

    $file_email     = $request['email'] . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg';
    $old_file_email = $old_email . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg';
    $update = false;

    if (Storage::disk('local')->has($old_file_email)) {
        $old_file = Storage::disk('local')->get($old_file_email);
        Storage::disk('local')->put($file_email, $old_file);
        $update = true;
    }

    if ($file) {
        Storage::disk('local')->put($file_email, File::get($file));
    }

    if ($update && $old_file_email !== $file_email) {
        Storage::delete($old_file_email);
    }
    return redirect()->route('account');
}

public function getUserImage()
{
    $user  = Auth::user();
    $image ="". $user->email . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg';
    $file  = Storage::disk('local')->get($image);
    return Response::make($file,200,[ 'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']);


}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/account', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getAccount',
'as'   => 'account'
]);

Route::post('/upateaccount', [
'uses' => 'UserController@postSaveAccount',
'as'   => 'account.save'
]);

Route::get('/userimage', [ 
'uses' => 'UserController@getUserImage',
'as'   => 'account.image'
]);
```

**View**

```
 <img src="{{ route('account.image')}}">
```

**Repository GitLab**
https://gitlab.com/ronnyere/imageUploadLaravel.git

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use one extension to store the uploaded images

To encode all of the possible image extensions to one extension, you can use [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/api/encode)

You can change the extension of all of the uploaded images by using...

```
Image::make($request->file('image')->getRealPath())->encode('jpg');
```

You can change `jpg` to another extensions as well